# Excelのシートの保護

Tags: excel

Excel 2013を使っています。
行方向のデータ数が可変なシートで、シートの上部６行を保護、スクロール固定にしたいのですが、
これを行うと、６行以降の行で、セルの挿入や、コピーしたセルの挿入での貼り付けが出来なくなって困っています。

具体的には、１から６行を行選択して、セル書式の設定 > 保護 > ロック
校閲 > シート保護 で、
ロックされていないセル範囲の選択
行の挿入
行の削除
などをにチェックして、シートをロックされたセルの内容を保護するをチェックしてＯＫしています。

保護状態で、コピーや、貼り付け、行に挿入削除は出来ますが、セルの挿入削除ができなくなります。
保護は、こう言うものなのでしょうか？

一番上の１３列、６行だけを保護し、７行以下はコピーしたセルの挿入などしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Comment: この記事 [EXCEL 一部のセルだけ入力禁止や入力許可する方法](https://excel-komarigoto.com/excel%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8B%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF/excel%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E4%BF%9D%E8%AD%B7%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/excel%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E7%A6%81%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%84%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E8%A8%B1%E5%8F%AF%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/) とかで出来るのでは？

Comment: 記事に書かれている方法で、セルの保護は出来るのです。ただ、この方法で保護すると、セルの挿入が出来なくなってしまうのです。

Comment: なるほど、それはちょっと分からないですね。